# downgrade jquery version on specific view only

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

let's say that I'm using jquery version 1.10 inside _Layout.cshtml and on specific pages to downgrade to 1.7.2.

How can I do this without changing Layout on this specific views? Is this even possible ? :)

Answer (score 0):

1) As one option you could create some base layout file and 2 sub layouts, one with jQuery v 1.10.x and another with jQuery 1.7.2. You will also need to explicitly specify layout files in your views
2) You could create mandatory jQuery section like `@RenderSection("jquery", required: true)` and put needed version on your views